# Writing to private dataset in using CARTO's SQL API?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I know applications can only read from public datasets but I am interested in writing to CARTO from a data collection app to a private dataset.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have two approaches

- Writing a middleware application that sends authenticated SQL API requests from that backend. [Example here](https://github.com/CartoDB/labs-middleware). This is the recommended approach because you can control better they security of your own backend.
- Writing a function with a security define (details [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-workshop/blob/master/04-database/exercises/sql_stored_procedures.md#functions-with-security-definer). In this case anyone that understands how your function works will be able to use it without any type of authorization.